# How to create relationships between Taxonomy vocabularies?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

I'm trying to build a site with similar content conventions to Craigslist. The problem is, I don't really know a good way to create multiple vocabulary relationships in drupal. Here's the end result I need:

**Vocabs:**
*Locations*
*Categories* (contains 'Goods' and 'Services')
*Status*

**Content Type:** 
Item

> **Relationships:**
>
> - User has many Items
> - User has one Location
> - Location has many Users
> - Location has all Categories
> - Item has many Categories
> - Item has one Location

The end result is having all ***Locations*** be easy to navigate, with ***Items*** being appropriately displayed, in multiple ***Categories***, but restricted to ***Locations***. ***Users*** should also be redirected to their respective locations based on their assigned ***Location*** and should be able to create ***Items*** without having to manually stipulate the ***Location*** they are already in.

**Does that make sense? Can this be done easily in Drupal?**

Answer (score 4):

This can all be done with Drupal's built in taxonomy module and the [User Terms](http://drupal.org/project/user_terms) module.

- Create a node type for Items.
- Any Item a user creates is automatically tied to them by them being the author.
- Create a taxonomy for Locations and assign it to Items and Users.
- Create a taxonomy for Categories, assign it to Items, make it multi selectable.

You can then use Views to create all the different listings pages and blocks.